# How do I know website slowness is related to network or my server

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, performance

I do know that my php pages generate in less than 0.1 seconds.

And also I do know that apache max clients has not been ran out.

And website is slowness is confirmed by testing from different locations.

Now, Can I be assured that the website slowness is from datacenter network and not my server?

Comment: Benchmark a static HTML page on another server in the datacenter's network, maybe?

Comment: It was slow even for static data

Comment: That would seem to suggest the datacenter network, I suppose, especially if you tested from a variety of locations. Do you have a reason to believe your datacenter provider is crap?

Comment: I don't know It is hetzner. Website was slow for about one hour.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ab (Apache Bench) to test your response time from different locations: your own server, a system on the same network, and so on. You can get an idea on where's the bottleneck.

Comment: website was slow from different locations